# struggling to bind "-" key in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I'm trying to make a calculator app with Tkinter, and have successfully bound all other key in this way, but I'm unable to bind my "-" key, I know that it's currently reading it as any character, and that I should probably escape it, but I don't know how.

```
root.bind("<KeyPress-->", lambda event: color_press(bsub, 'activebackground'))
```

I've already tried

```
root.bind("<KeyPress-\->", lambda event: color_press(bsub, 'activebackground'))
```

unsure what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
root.bind("<KeyPress-minus>", lambda event: color_press(bsub, 'activebackground'))
```

Comment: wow, can't believe I didn't try that. Really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! If this did the trick for you, please accept the answer so others know that this question has been answered already.